# Python: restore distance full graph from sparse matrix

Tags: python, graph, distance

I am trying to emulate bacteria growth. Say, each species performs 1 reaction to turn substance A to substance B and gain (or lose) energy.

If I use a small number of substances, I can check for infinite generating cycles by hand (e.g. A => B => C => A pathway has a positive energy gain). BUt if I use, say, 10 substances, things are getting complicated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def add_symmetry(df):
    for i in df.index:
        for j in df.columns:
            if df.loc[i,j]!=0:
                df.loc[j,i] = -1*(df.loc[i,j])
    return(df)

names = [_ for _ in 'ABCDEFGHJK']

en_df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10,10)), index=names, columns=names)

en_df.loc['A','F'] = 1.9
en_df.loc['F','B'] = 0.8
en_df.loc['B', 'G'] = 4.6
en_df.loc['G','C'] = 1.5
en_df.loc['C','A'] = -9.4

# cycle2
en_df.loc['D','H'] = -5
en_df.loc['H','E'] = 2
en_df.loc['E','J'] = 1.1

en_df.loc['K','E'] = 1.2

en_df.loc['G','H'] = -1

en_df = add_symmetry(en_df)

     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    J    K
A  0.0  0.0  9.4  0.0  0.0  1.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.8  4.6  0.0  0.0  0.0
C -9.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.5  0.0  0.0  0.0
D  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -5.0  0.0  0.0
E  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -2.0  1.1 -1.2
F -1.9  0.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
G  0.0 -4.6  1.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0  0.0  0.0
H  0.0  0.0  0.0  5.0  2.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
J  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
K  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

This gives me a symmetric matrix with 10 reactions out of 45 total. I want to fill in the rest automatically so that there are no positive sum cycles.
E.g.:

```
A=>F is +1.9 energy units
F=>B is +0.8 eu
A => B is (1.9 + 0.8 - 0.1) = 2.6 eu
```

etc for the rest

Is there an easy way to do that or do I need to implement an optimal path search algorithm for each zero cell?

Answer (score 0):

So far, my solution looks like this

```
import copy
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from collections import deque


def add_symmetry(df):

    for i in df.index:
        for j in df.columns:
            if df.loc[i,j]!=0:
                df.loc[j,i] = -1*(df.loc[i,j])

    return(df)

def from_pd_df(df):

    gr = nx.DiGraph()
    for i in df.index:
        for j in df.columns:
            if df.loc[i, j] != 0:
                gr.add_edge(i, j, weight=df.loc[i, j])
    return(gr)

def fill_zeros(df):

    temp = copy.copy(df)

    # Deal only with positive energies
    # Substitute maximal path problem with a minimal path one
    temp[temp<0] = 0
    temp = -1*temp

    gr = from_pd_df(temp)

    for i in temp.index:

        try:
            p = nx.bellman_ford(gr, i, weight = 'weight')

        except nx.NetworkXUnbounded:
            print('{} is involved in an infinite cycle'.format(i))

            return(None)
   # If a previously implicit path exists, save it ti temp
        for j in p[1]:
            if df.loc[i,j] == 0:
                temp.loc[i,j] = p[1][j]
                temp.loc[j, i] = -1*p[1][j]
    # Revert back to maximal path problem   
    temp = -1*temp

    # Add reverse reaction
    temp = add_symmetry(temp)

    return(temp)

>> Define the matrix


en_df = add_symmetry(en_df)
x = fill_zeros(en_df)
```